# ios radar screen for an app using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I need to show a radar screen on a map in a ios app using swift. The radar view is on top of a map view which has some markers. The dial just goes round and round.

(The next requirement is to highlight/blink the markers that occurred in the map x seconds back once the dial touches it )

Any ideas on how I can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is not a "tell me how to `<my app requirements>`" site.

To get your started, take a look at `CAAnimation`. You can animate the keyPath `transform.rotation.z` to apply a rotation of an arbitrary amount to a layer's view.

I found a link showing the code to do rotation on a view in Swift at this link:

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/15/rotate-animation-in-swift/

The key bit from that link is this code:

```
extension UIView {
    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration

        if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
            rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
        }
        self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

That's not the whole solution to your problem, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you, this should get me started